# Colorize a tab in a JTabbedPane using java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am trying to change the background color of my tabs in a `JTabbedPane`. I tried `JTabbedPane.setBackgroudAt(0, Color.GRAY)` and `JTabbedPane.setBackgroud(Color.GRAY)` and the foreground too, but nothing happens. I changed the background of the panel inside the tab, still nothing.

[image]

**Edit 1:** I'm using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");` if this can help with the solution

**Edit 2:** Link to a example, https://www.dropbox.com/s/0krn9vikvkq46mz/JavaApplication4.rar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color of JTabbedPane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752037/how-to-change-background-color-of-jtabbedpane)

Comment: Which do you want to change, the tab or the tab's content?

Comment: i want change the tab, this black part has to be gray like que content. Anda i read this quetion trashgod, but nothing there help me, so i create one myself :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I've suggested two options [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11334283/230513).

Comment: sorry, i want to say, the white part need be gray like the gray in the bottom of the image!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- most of method for `JTabbedPane` is protected in the API, and not accesible from Swing methods
- have to look for `Custom XxxTabbedPaneUI`, override these methods, and could be accesible from outside
- correct way would be to implement [Custom Look & Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968) only, part of them override `JTabbedPane`
- example for [Custom XxxTabbedPaneUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056093/714968)

Comment: i was avoiding this because it looks like more complicated, but i try and works very very well, perfect! you are very good man, i can even make more things that the expected, very very thank you man!

Answer (score 19):

You can change the background color of the tab using `setBackgroundAt()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513).

[image: tab]

You can change the background color of the tab's content using `setBackground()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349106/230513). Typically you have to do this on the tab's content, as the enclosing `JTabbedPane` background color is obscured by the content.

[image: content]

If you still have trouble, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) based on either example that exhibits the problem you envounter.

Addendum: Combining the methods is also possible:

[image: combined]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTabbedTest {

    private static JTabbedPane jtp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                jtp = new JTabbedPane();
                jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 200));
                jtp.addTab("Reds", new ColorPanel(0, Color.RED));
                jtp.setBackgroundAt(0, Color.RED);
                jtp.addTab("Greens", new ColorPanel(1, Color.GREEN));
                jtp.setBackgroundAt(1, Color.GREEN);
                jtp.addTab("Blues", new ColorPanel(2, Color.BLUE));
                jtp.setBackgroundAt(2, Color.BLUE);

                f.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class ColorPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private final Random rnd = new Random();
        private final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        private Color color;
        private Color original;
        private int mask;
        private JLabel label = new JLabel("Stackoverflow!");
        private int index;

        public ColorPanel(int index, Color color) {
            super(true);
            this.color = color;
            this.original = color;
            this.mask = color.getRGB();
            this.index = index;
            this.setBackground(color);
            label.setForeground(color);
            this.add(label);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            color = new Color(rnd.nextInt() & mask);
            this.setBackground(color);
            jtp.setBackgroundAt(index, original);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your example was inaccessible to me; I've combined the two approaches above.

Comment: well, i will try this, if not work i will find another place to put my exemple, thanks

Comment: @evandrobm you issue is used Win7 or Vista, use custom Look and Feel

Comment: i'm using win 7, and i use UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

Comment: As mentioned by @evandrobm above, this does not work with WindowsLookAndFeel, tested with JRE x86 1.8.0_181 and JRE x64 1.8.0_172.  It is noted in the API documentation that "It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose to ignore it.".

Comment: Although it works in this example, note that better practice to instantiate the JTabbedPane on the EDT, not in a static section.

Comment: @opeongo: Good point; see also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) regarding `setPreferredSize()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using a Look and Feel that does what you want, or failing that, changing the default UIManger settings for a JTabbedPane:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background", Color.GRAY);
```

If you opt for the latter, it must be done before you create your GUI.

For more on this, please see Rob Camick's excellent blog on the subject: [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Edit: I was wrong. It should be:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.unselectedBackground", Color.GRAY);
```

But note that this may not work with every Look and Feel.

Comment: i put this line of code after i set the look and feel, but nothing changes too...

Comment: not work again, i'm using com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

Answer (score -3):

It may be a problem that there is nothing added yet to the tab.

Try setting the content manager of the content panel to `BorderLayout`, adding a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`. Center and then coloring that panel.

Comment: There's not a chance in Hades of this suggestion working, sorry.